# How to remove whitespace at bottom of each react view?

Tags: css, reactjs

my react app has a nav bar that displays different views. I noticed that each view has the same whitespace at the bottom of each of the views, between the content on the view and the footer. I have tried adding the following to the css from other stack overflow questions:

```
html, body, #app, #app>div {


height: 100%
}

body {
  background-color: #161e30;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace; 
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #161e30;
  height: 100%
}
```

As you can see, I have added height: 100% to everything, but still have this problem:

[image]

There is this random whitespace on each of my views between my content and the footer(the thin bottom dark bar is the footer). I am using react-bootstrap for a lot of my styling and layout, but have an App.css file where I added fonts, colors, and height. What can I add to fix this issue?

Comment: try setting height in the body to `100vh`

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work

Comment: Would you be able to throw your code in a codepen or sandbox. I'd like to tinker with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<footer id="footer"/>` to the end of body tag and then in CSS add something like this:

```
#footer{
    height: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10em;
}
```

Adjust bottom margin until You get the wanted result.